# What kind of matrix factorization is this ? and how to find such factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Suppose M is a n × n real or complex matrix, and we are interested in the following matrix factorization:

${\displaystyle {{M} = {H} {\Sigma }} {H} ^{*} }$

**Where:**

${H}$ is a n × n matrix , and ${H}$ <sup>*</sup> is the conjugate transpose of ${H}$.

${\Sigma }$ can be any n × n matrix

**Question 1:** What kind of matrix factorization is this ? How to find ${H}$  and ${\Sigma }$ for a given ${H}$ ?  We know that such factorization will not be unique. We are just interested in an algorithm to find general solutions.

**Question 2:** If we restrict ${\Sigma }$ to be a positive semidefinite matrix, then what kind of matrix factorization is this ? and how to find such factorization ? Will such factorization be unique or not ? (We assume it is NOT).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: If $H$ is invertible (a coordinate transform) then this formular gives the transformation of matrices associated to bilinear forms.

Given $M$, setting $H=I$ and $\Sigma=M$ is valid.

Q2: If $\Sigma$ is Hermitian and positive definite then $M$ is positive semidefinite at least (positive definite iff $H$ is invertible).

Given such a factorization $M=H\Sigma H^*$  and a unitary operator $U$, then
$M = (HU)(U^*\Sigma U)(HU)^*$ is a new factorization.

If you restrict $M$ to be symmetric, $H$ to be orthogonal matrices, then a normal form associated to this transformation is given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: Thank you for the  reply !